# My bcrypt password validation always fails, saying hashedPassword is not the hash of the given passwordPASS

Tags: go, encryption, bcrypt

```
func validateCredentials(attemptedPassword string, actualPasswordHash string) (bool, error) {
    if err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(actualPasswordHash), []byte(attemptedPassword)); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("validateCredentials error is %v", err)
        return false, nil
    }

    return true, nil
}
```

I wrote a test that looks like this:

```
func TestAuth_validateCredentials(t *testing.T) {
    var actualPassword = "hello123"
    actualPasswordHash, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(actualPassword), bcrypt.MinCost)
    if valid, err := validateCredentials("username", string(actualPasswordHash)); err != nil {
        t.Error("Unexpted error: ", err)
    } else if valid {
        t.Error("Expected invalid when password is wrong")
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> validateCredentials error is crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the
>   hash of the given passwordPASS

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `"username"` instead of `actualPassword`

```
if valid, err := validateCredentials(actualPassword, string(actualPasswordHash))
```